# JQUERY - tomar indice de elemento creado dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

estoy tratando de tomar el indice de un elemento creado dinamicamente que tengo en una lista, aca les dejo las estructura del DOM

```
<section class="cd-horizontal-timeline loaded" id="timelineSection">
   <div class="timeline">
      <div class="events-wrapper">
         <div class="events" style="width: 300px; transform: translatex(-120px);">
            <ol>
               <li><a href="url" ></a> </li>
               <li><a href="url" ></a> </li>
               <li><a class="selected" href="url" ></a> </li>
            </ol>
            <span class="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span> </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="cd-timeline-navigation">
          <li> 
             <a class="prev" href="#0">Prev</a>
          </li>
          <li> 
             <a class="next" href="#0">Next</a>
          </li>
          <button id="closeTimeline" type="button">Chiudi</button>
       </ul>
   </div>
</section>
```

hasta el momento he probado a hacer lo siguiente:

`$("a.selected").index($('.events ol li'));`  resultado : -1 (en cualquier indice este el elemento)

`$(".events ol li").index('a.selected');` resultado : siempre -1 como antes

`$("a.selected").parent().index();` resultado : siempre 0

`$("a.selected").closest("li").index()` resultado : siempre 0

pero no tube ningun tipo de resultado ..

**EDIT**

tratando de tomar el indice :

```
$("button#linetime").on("click", function(){
    var eventsLength = $(".events ol li").length;
    var selectedIndex = $("a.selected").index($('.events ol li'));
    alert(selectedIndex);
    $("section#timelineSection").toggle();
    if ($("a.selected").parent().is(":last-child") ){
        $("a.next").click();
    }
});
```

creando los elementos :

```
$.ajax({
    url: url ,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data){
        var dataAtt;
        var date;

        for(var i = 0 ; i < $(data.d.results).length; i++){
            var dataCreaz = new Date(data.d.results[i].Modified);
            var mese = dataCreaz.getMonth()+1
            if(mese <10)
                mese = "0"+mese;
                date = dataCreaz.getDay() + "/" + mese + "/" + dataCreaz.getFullYear();
            if (data.d.results[i].Id === itemId){
                $("div.events ol").append("<li><a class='selected' href='#0' data-date='"+dataCreaz+"'>"+date+"</a></li>");
            }else{
                $("div.events ol").append("<li><a target='_blank' href='#0' data-date='"+date+"'>"+date+"</a></li>");
            }
        };
    },
    error: function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    } 
});
```

**EDIT 2**
[image: DOM CREADO DINAMICAMENTE]

Comment: Buenas, puedes poner el código donde tratas de tomar el índice? También serviría el código donde creas estos elementos dinámicamente.

Comment: @JCAguilera ahi he agregado el codigo que me faltaba

Comment: Donde está `button#linetime`?

Comment: @JCAguilera es el boton que sirve para visualizar la section de la Linetime, que la tengo escondida, lo unico que hace es el toggle() digamos, el indice me sirve para poder alinear la linea del tiempo, ya que por default si el evento seleccionado esta en el fondo me lo alinea a la izquierda, y esto me sirve para poder alinearla a la derecha, para que no quede mal la parte grafica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que veo de tu código, puedes intentar con esta solución:

```
$(".events ol li a.selected").parent().index();
```

Esto selecciona un elemento `a` con clase `selected`, toma el índice del elemento padre (en este caso `li` dento de `ol` dentro de `events`) y devuelve su posición (dentro de `ol`).

Ahora, ¿por qué no está funcionando? Puede ser por que al momento de crear dinámicamente los elementos `<li><a><a></li>` creas algunos `a` con clase `selected`, lo que hace que hayan varios `a.selected`, lo que dificulta decidir de cual padre quieres tomar el índice.

Lo que puedes hacer es, antes de crear otro elemento a.selected, quites la clase selected del resto de los elementos selected, para que haya solo uno:

```
if (data.d.results[i].Id === itemId){
    $('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $("div.events ol").append("<li><a class='selected' href='#0' data-date='"+dataCreaz+"'>"+date+"</a></li>");
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: no, yo tambien lo pensaba, pero la creacion funciona bien, tengo un solo elemento con clase selected, pondrè la imagen en la pregunta

Comment: Ok, entonces puedes intentar haciendo esto: `$(".events ol li a.selected").parent().index()`

Comment: perfecto funciona ! muchisimas gracias ! edita la respuesta asi te la puedo votar como correcta !

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás buscando un elemento entre los `li` pero donde tienes que buscar es entre los hijos de esos `li`:

```js
console.log($(".events ol li").children().index($("a.selected")));
console.log($(".events ol li").children().index($("a.notSelected")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cd-horizontal-timeline loaded" id="timelineSection">
   <div class="timeline">
      <div class="events-wrapper">
         <div class="events" style="width: 300px; transform: translatex(-120px);">
            <ol>
               <li><a href="url" ></a></li>
               <li><a class="notSelected" href="url" ></a></li>
               <li><a class="selected" href="url" ></a></li>
            </ol>
            <span class="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span> </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="cd-timeline-navigation">
          <li> 
             <a class="prev" href="#0">Prev</a>
          </li>
          <li> 
             <a class="next" href="#0">Next</a>
          </li>
          <button id="closeTimeline" type="button">Chiudi</button>
       </ul>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: me da siempre -1 como resultado, siendo el ultimo elemento entre 14 :/